# Why did launching gedit suddenly get slow?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, gedit

###### setup:

ubuntu 20.04.3, updated daily

###### background:

For years, I have launched gedit from the terminal. Frequently. Without issue.

###### problem:

As of a few weeks ago, on a laptop and two desktops of varying horsepower (all running 20.04.3 and all updated roughly daily), gedit started taking around a minute to load. Sometimes minutes.

Ummmm...  Anyone know what is going on? Fix?

Comment: Can you try with a newly created user on the same system?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Thank you for the suggestion. Just did this. gedit loaded real snappy-like on that account. Know something about this?

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes, application configuration data may get messed up and this may have adverse effects on application startup. For example, they may contain some references to network resources that are no longer available.

The `gedit` application seems to have three places that keep some configuration and application data:

1. The `$HOME/.config/gedit` directory contains some application configuration data files, like accelerator keys, page and print setup info, and tools (scripts) called by `gedit`.
2. The `$HOME/.local/share/gedit/` directory contains the `gedit-metadata.xml` file which keeps information about files opened by `gedit`.
3. “**dconf database**” that can accessed by running `dconf-editor`.

I presume, the culprit is the `gedit-metadata.xml` file. Close all open `gedit` windows and rename this file. Then try to restart `gedit`. If this does not work, please look for other files under the `$HOME/.local/share/gedit/` directory and try to rename them one by one. Some files in this directory seem to have been deprecated, so the file modification date may be a clue here.

If this doesn’t solve your problem, you may similarly try to rename the contents of the `$HOME/.config/gedit` directory.

If this still doesn’t solve your problem, you can start `dconf-editor`, navigate to branch “ **/ org / gnome / gedit** ” and try to reset configuration values to their defaults.

Another place that I would look at would be to disable (again one by one) the `gedit` plugins: Select **Preferences** in `gedit` and go to the **Plugins** tab. From there, you can disable all the plugins and then enable them one by one by quitting `gedit` and restarting it each time.

__

Please, comment on what you have done and what solved your problem.

Comment: Disabling the File Browser Panel plugin did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

While executing gedit, prepend the command with `strace`, for example

```
$ strace gedit |& tee gedit-strace.log
```

When you pipe the strace to a file, you can see which system calls are used. In my case, gedit is attempting to open a mounted file system. This mount point contained details for a network file server (NFS) that fails to resolve.

gedit is attempting to open this mount point, but it will always fail and takes a very long time to timeout.

To solve this, unmount the mount points that take a long time to fail.

```
# umount /mnt/nfserver
```

In my case, gedit starts up instantly after this.